# How do I enable redirection on a domain for an S3-hosted website with CloudFront in front of it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to get redirects to work within a domain name for an S3-hosted static website. That is, if I point mydomain.com/foo, I want it to redirect to mydomain.com; this *should* basically mirror mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo being redirected to mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. What's happening right now is mydomain.com/foo gets redirected to mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/.

I have an S3 bucket named in line with [Amazon docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs) in order to ensure resources are redirected appropriately. I also have CloudFront configured to point to the S3 website endpoint (mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com), as well as the domain set up in "Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)".

In Route53, I've created an A record to point to the CloudFront's d123456789.cloudfront.net domain name. So, right now going to mydomain.com works just fine; however, trying to go to a resource that would cause a redirect gets me back to the ugly S3 name.

How can I keep CloudFront in the mix but get friendly redirection behavior that keeps my domain name front and center?

Edit: For example purposes, I'm trying to just redirect /upload to /; here's how I've set that up:
[image: S3 Redirect Screenshot]

Edit 2: To clarify, redirecting foo.com/update to foo.com/index.html is the minimal case; ideally I'd like to be able to redirect *any* resource under foo.com/ to foo.com/index.html, which is why I was pursuing the redirect rules solution.

Comment: Can you post a link to the website so we can have a look? Can you also post details of how your redirect is set up - maybe a screenshot?

Comment: @Tim unfortunately, I the website an internal/testing one, so I can't post a link to the website; I've added a screenshot of an example of how I'm handling the redirects at the S3 level. Does that help? (And thanks for the response!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the target hostname and protocol in the routing rules.  This forces the `Location:` to have the correct (desired) hostname.

The simplest approach for redirecting almost everything is creating a routing rule that matches `403 Forbidden` (since S3 denies everything by default) and points where you want things to go.

```
<RoutingRules>
 <RoutingRule>
  <Condition>
    <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
  </Condition>
  <Redirect>
   <Protocol>https</Protocol> 
   <HostName>target.example.com</HostName>
   <ReplaceKeyWith></ReplaceKeyWith>
  </Redirect>
 </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

All requests should redirect to `https://target.example.com/`, unless the requested URL matches an existing object with the `public-read` ACL, or an index document.

If this doesn't behave as expected, you can also change it to match on 404, but don't do that.  If 404 works, this means your bucket policy is too permissive, allowing unauthenticated users to list your bucket contents... so, don't change this -- fix your policy. Use 403 here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the advanced redirect routing rules for this. Simply upload a zero byte object with the name of the redirect and set a redirect under the metadata. This is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html).

One gotcha is you have to access it using the URL format below, or on the actual domain, as described on [this support case](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=402377) (AWS login required).

```
http://BUCKET_NAME.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/index.html
```

This works just fine with S3 accessed directly, with or without Route53 being used for DNS.

**Update**: I've done an example of this using S3 and CloudFront, which I'll leave up for a few days, but I'll provide screenshots to show what I did so it can serve as a permanent example. You can try the redirect out [here](http://s3statictest.photographerstechsupport.com/redir.html) - the redir.html file should redirect back to index.html.

This works fine when accessed through CloudFront, but you have to type your origin into CF manually, rather than use the dropdown list. [Information here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-create-cfdist.html). This is because only the website endpoints support redirects - [information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740084/amazon-s3-redirect-and-cloudfront).

Here's the way I set up the redirect on S3
[image]

Here's an example of a redirect to an external website ([link](http://s3statictest.photographerstechsupport.com/ama))
[image]

Here's how I set up CloudFlare with a cname for cloudfront
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tim! I updated my question; ideally, I'd like to be able to redirect ANY resource after foo.com/ to foo.com/index.html, but getting the minimum case to work is also useful, so thank you so much. :) And I'd appreciate the CloudFront example! I followed your example above (using CloudFront) and I got a 403 Forbidden error. Hmm.

Comment: I got a 403 forbidden when I requested the root of the CF distribution, I fixed it by adding a default root object. I think I've set up CloudFront origin incorrectly, according to this answer, so I've fixed that and I'm waiting for it to propagate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740084/amazon-s3-redirect-and-cloudfront documented here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-create-cfdist.html. Do you mean you want to do wildcard redirects? That might take the advanced redirect rules - I haven't looked at them.

Comment: Yep- ultimately I'm looking to do wildcard redirects, if at all possible!

Comment: That would've been a useful thing to put in your question. Michael's answer should solve your problem. Interesting thing to look into though.

Comment: @Tim- you're right. My apologies! I clarified the question,. but definitely understand it could have been framed more clearly. Thanks again for the help!